# Inner Filter Not working Properly in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have array of static data sized 3.

I am displaying array in right side.

There's one textbox above it for filter.
I have taken 2 models for it.

One is `field` and second is `subfield`.

one field can have multiple `sub fields`.
I am filtering on `field` as well as on `subfields`.
It works on fields but shows me some weir output on `subfields`.
there's only one condition that if `field's filtered data` is added in array then it should not go for `subfield`, if no match found in field then it can go in `subfields` and then add data to filtered array.

my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/72qF7/2/)

Comment: what problem you are facing. i think it is working fine.

Comment: @Akhlesh - when I write `s` in textbox it is repeating the main fields.

Comment: @Akhlesh - the link shows `NOT FOUND`, link is expired or misspelled.

Comment: That link is expired. see this http://embed.plnkr.co/WvpQg0tK40BkqDAXpTSQ/preview

Comment: @Akhlesh - See when I add `t` then 145 repeat twice. & when I add `e` then lot's of repeats there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in condition which you are using for filtering data.As you have more then two subfield so for every match of subfield same data pushed into arr that is the main reason of getting unexpected result.

```
 self.filteredList = ko.computed(function() {
  var filter = self.filter(),
  arr = [];
if (filter) {
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.controlFields(), function(item) {
    if (item.code().match(filter) || item.title().toLowerCase().match(filter.toLowerCase())) {
      arr.push(item);
    }
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.subFields(), function(sf) {
        if (sf.title().toLowerCase().match(filter.toLowerCase())) {
          var found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(arr, function(k) {
            return item.title() === k.title() && item.code()===k.code();
          });
          if (!found) {
            arr.push(item);
          }
        }
      });

   });
  } else {
   arr = self.controlFields();
  }
 return arr;
});
```

[***Demo***](http://embed.plnkr.co/WvpQg0tK40BkqDAXpTSQ/preview)

Comment: Yes, it's working fine.. Sorry I exactly don't know much about the Knockout so stuck in problem. BTW Thank u again.

Comment: Hey Akhlesh, Did you know How to load static resource using Knockout ? I have posted question, if you have time then will you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205211/load-static-resource-in-spring-using-knockout-js